# Issue while running "npx react-native run-android". How to solve it?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, build.gradle, development-environment, android-sdk-manager

Created a project using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`. While running `npx react-native run-android` in other terminal, I am getting the following error. I tried to follow React Native CLI Quickstart in https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. I have installed python2, openjdk8, nodejs separately, later deleted them and reinstalled using chocolatey. I have reinstalled AndroidSDK tools, AVD multiple times still getting the same error.

````
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'C:\Users\Raja' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
'C:\Users\Raja' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Raja' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Raja Naveen\Desktop\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 84

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not open dsl remapped class cache for 7f1u5qpw1jm8dwv3ri20amyrz (C:\Users\Raja Naveen\.gradle\caches\6.2\scripts-remapped\react_dysq7qqrljy3c2uubmf33rsun\7f1u5qpw1jm8dwv3ri20amyrz\dslcf39471ad2848fb82befe662c0627ed4).
   > 0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 33s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the android SDK paths in the enivironment varailble"

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**EDIT**:
Make sure you have either a running emulator by creating one in Android studio or connected physical devices with USB debugging turned on.

Comment: can you print `$ANDROID_HOME` in the terminal and also make sure you restart the terminal after updating paths

Comment: Updated the answer, make sure you have setup emulator

Comment: verified, they are good. I think the problem is then not with the env-setup. Emulator setup is good too.

Comment: Can you share what you have added in the paths

Comment: C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk,C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools,C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator,C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools,C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin - these are added in path.  C:\Users\Raja Naveen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk - added as ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to set the ANDROID_HOME & JAVA_HOME in your environments variables if you are in Windows and in either the bashrc or the zshr  if you are using a Mac
 
JAVA_HOME => C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u262-b10
ANDROID_HOME => C:\Users\laptopName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk>

P.S: On Windows just enter env in the search bar and click on the first tab then click on New and add those then you are good to go.
```

Comment: Can you please run adb,  java and javac in the command line and give me the result ? are you using a Mac or a Windows and was the project initalize in a different OS?

Comment: I am using Windows, I have initialised project like 4-5 days ago. I run adb, java, javac in cmd, they are showing usage options.

Comment: Try to add this line in the build.gradle of the app   in the android bracket android {
    compileSdkVersion 27 ...}

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
 > compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

is problem.
Add

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

in build.gradle

Comment: I have tried your answer by placing above lines in android\app\build.gradle. My version is diff., so I tried with compileSdkVersion 29 buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'. I tried with both numbers, still error exists.